# Choose E-Commerce Platform with SOLR for Faceted Navigation,Search,Autocomplete

Tags: php, magento, solr, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I have good experience in E-commerce platforms in ASP.NET, LIKE ASPDOTNETSTOREFRONT, NopCommerce, DashCommerce, AbleCommerce BVCommerce etc..

However, when I am looking at the Large – Mega E-commerce store – it is either built on top of PHP or Java frameworks ! May be I am wrong…

but I am referring to BestBuy, BHPhotoVideo,WallMart etc - From USA - FlipKart, Jabong, Myntra– from India. All of these website has Great Faceted Navigation (Filters), which has been implemented with SOLR – (java – Lucene). With SOLR these website has implemented Auto-Completed, Did you mean, Cross Sell Products, Related Products and Facets (Filters). SOLR is one of the best searching platform for Faceted Navigation and robust Search.

So I am looking to make one e-commerce website in India where SOLR is integrated OUT-OF-BOX! I would prefer SOLR Search with ASP.NET Platform but I am not finding any.

Can you guys suggest me E-commerce Platform having SOLR OUT-Box-Box or available as ADD-On. Example - Magento Enterprise Edition – having OUT-OF-Box SOLR ! or Magento CE can be extended with FREE SOLR ADD-On available.

Please suggest me E-commerce platform to make website in India. Key feature should be

1) SOLR Integration – OUT-OF-Box

2) If SOLR is not OUT-OF-BOX – Addon should be available

3) Should be open source or available with Source Code Option

4) Easily Customizable Code and well maintain code architecture.

5) Easy availability of readymade Themes/ Skins would be great

Looking for your valuable suggestion to choose E-Commerce Platform with SOLR option.

-Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer an ASP.NET platform I think nopCommerce is a very good choice, with its most recent release (v3.2) there has been made significant performance optimizations. It qualifies for your key features 2-5. Solr integration can be found [here](http://www.nopaccelerate.com/).

Comment: Gusten, Thanks. I am aware that with nopAccelerate, but I am thinking Magento has more built-in feature then NopCommerce even in community edition. What do you ?

Comment: Even as it is Magento is OpenSource there are lost of plug-in available in the market as Free or with in lower cost as well. that is the main benefit of Opensource. So I am still in confusion which to choose NopCommerce(I have good experience in .NET as well as Nopcommerce) or Magento (PHP-I don't have experience)

Comment: Pls watch this video - it has good comparison of Magento and nopCommerce https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq0JTxjUjeQ